# Regexp for removing certain IMG tags

Tags: html, regex

Need a regexp to remove all the HTML tags like:

```
<img border="0" alt="" src="/images/stories/j25.png">
```

Comment: Why? What language? Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: From a String? Or the DOM?

Comment: Exactly like that? or with different border values? or with different file names? In a large chunk of HTML? On the client? On the server? As a one off task, or before render each time?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').find('img').each(function(i) { 
       var src=$(this).attr('src');
       if(src=="/images/stories/j25.png") {
        $(this).remove();
       }
    }); 
});
```